# bVI Root Substitution

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Curious as to why this substitution of the root for a ♭VI chord works. It's pretty standard but I don't get the theory of it. I recently saw it being used in the context of a  ii - V - I to delay the final resolve of a song. Specifically the following:

|| A7#11(13) Amin9 | C/D D7b9 | EbMaj7♯11(13) ||

I've seen other progressions walk up to resolve as such: ii - V - ♭VI - ♭VII - I

What is the theory surrounding a ♭VI substitution like this?

Comment: Can you please write this in a very for-dummies way, like where is your "one" i.e. I chord, and what has been substituted with what? A root has been substituted? Which root, what note name? What was it substituted with? What does (13) in parenthesis mean, when you also say something about 7 and 11? Can you show all the notes you mean on a piano keyboard or something, and then mark them, which note you think is center, and where is the sixth that has been flatted. And where would the missing note be that was substituted with something, and what is the surprising thing about that.

Comment: Is it really necessary to give an example progression with #11, 13, b9, etc. to get to the point about a "root substitution?" Just use plain seventh chords and show the progression before and after the substitution.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I disagree. The progression I'm referencing was written as such and sharing it with the extensions is important to get a more detailed picture of leading tones with the substitution.

Comment: @Flyswat. No. Those extensions _obscure_ the details of the leading tone, and the other functional tones of the resolution, because those extension tones _are not involved with the resolution._

Comment: As a general rule, when people as "how it works" they are asking about _functional harmony_, and when it comes to functional harmony mode changing details and extensions beyond the seventh (probably better stated as the tritone MI/FA) are irrelevant to essential function. In other words, essential function ("how it works") can usually be explained with plain triads in combination with tritone MI/FA.

Comment: This applies to jazz too. That fact that `ii V I` is a jazz fundamental is _literally_ writing out the _functional_ essentials in terms of only triads.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Michael I presumed it would be helpful to share the literal progression. Next time I’ll stick to the 7’s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I recently saw it being used in the context of a ii - V - I to delay the final resolve of a song. Specifically the following:

> || A7#11(13) Amin9 | C/D D7b9 | EbMaj7♯11(13) ||

I suppose you're asking about the `D7b9` resolving to `Ebmaj7` rather than to a tonic `I` chord rooted on `G`.

This should be a straight forward question and answer, but it's complicated by all the complex details of the example progression - lots of chord extensions and mode changing - and the notion that `V ♭VI` is a "root substitution."

Progressions `V ♭VI` or `V vi` are simply *deceptive progressions*. The idea is commonly covered in harmony textbooks. Basically, the "deception" is instead of `V` going to the tonic `I` or `i`, it goes to the chord of the *submediant*, `vi` or `♭VI`. The "working" of that progression is the tritone of scale degrees `^4 ^7` resolves to `^3 ^1` in *both progressions* (`V I` and `V vi` of the minor mode versions) but the root of the second chord *changes.*

Using the basic idea of the example progression, it would be progressions the following where the tritone resolution is in the treble clef...

[image]

...those are not meant to be good jazz voicings. The idea is only to show the theoretical "workings" of the progressions which is the resolution of the tritone inward to a third or outward to a sixth.

It seems worth pointing out those progressions don't involve a root *substitution* but simply a root *change*, because it made the OP's question hard to understand.

The root of `I` (or `i`) is scale degree `^1`. When the progression moves to `♭VI` instead of `I` the root becomes scale degree `^6`, but importantly the `^1` is still present in the `♭VI` chord. Notice how `G` is still present in the deceptive resolution, but it becomes the chord's *third*...

[image]

If anything is being substituted in the chord of resolution it is scale degree `^5` (the chord's fifth not root) being substituted with scale degree `^6`. That nuance is probably more apparent when the chord of resolution is a plain triad, which is the basis of the "working", rather than jazz seventh chords.

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks for sharing Michael!

Answer (score 1):

It can operate in three ways:

- As a deceptive cadence, but using `bVI` from the parallel minor rather than the native `vi`.
- As a subdominant substitution. This is the case in the given `bVI - bVII - I` example, where the `bVI` leads to the dominant-function `bVII`.
- It can also be used to form a sort of plagal cadence, especially if used in first inversion. That puts the root in the bass, the `b6` can drop to `5` (as in a an actual plagal cadence), and the `b3` can rise to `3`.

Comment: Are there specific rules around borrowing from a parallel minor? Or is it just on a what works-is basis?

Comment: @Flyswat - I think my music theory textbooks actually implied you can borrow *everything* from the parallel minor at the risk of modulating to that parallel minor.

Comment: @Flyswat In the general way you're asking, yes, it's just a "it works if it works" type of thing. Dekkadeci said it well that the primary risk is an unintentional modulation.

Answer (score 0):

To me the theory behind why the V7-bVI works is that the tritone of the V7 chord, resolves in exactly the same way as it does in a V7-i. The bVI comes from the parallel minor. Using your example’s key of G, the F# leading tone of the D7 resolves up to a G and the C resolves down to a Bb. The notes G and Bb are in both the bVI (Eb) and the i (Gm) chords.

Comment: I mused on the A# as well. Been caught out by that printing before!. And why put the 13 in brackets, when there's 11 before it, presuming playing a 13 may well involve playing 11 too?

Comment: Yes John it is A dominant. The 7 has been added so that A7#11(13).

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're asking about the chord A♭ (or A♭7) followed by chord C, for example, in  key C.

If you are, there's only the C note in common, all the others are non-diatonic, which makes the listener pay more attention, expecting diatonics.

So, C, with CEG, and A♭7 with A♭ C E♭ G♭. It can come across as a key change - that chord is the V of C♯, a quite common key change up a semitone, which obviously doesn't happen.

Notes like to be heard to resolve cleanly, and one semitone is often the cleanest path to take. The E♭ will move to E, while both the G♭ and A♭ converge to the G.

It's *almost* a plagal cadence, which would be F>C, or Fm>C, as Fm is the relative of A♭, so using the parallel key, as Aaron states.